# Why are index statistics getting outdated, making queries slow?

Tags: sql-server

In the application, the following query is run:

```sql
SELECT [t].[Id], [t].[Name], [t2].[IsPrivate]
FROM [dbo].[Tasks] AS [t]
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT [p].[Id], [p].[CreatedBy], [p].[IsPrivate]
    FROM [dbo].[Projects] AS [p]
    WHERE [p].[WorkspaceId] = '4600c9d5-5afd-43a9-8f0b-53e571d0796a' AND [p].[DeletedOn] IS NULL
) AS [t2] ON [t].[ProjectId] = [t2].[Id]
WHERE [t].[WorkspaceId] = '4600c9d5-5afd-43a9-8f0b-53e571d0796a' AND [t].[DeletedOn] IS NULL
```

(The query above is just a shorter example of an actual query in the application, but it depicts well what is happening.)

Due to the usage of Entity Framework, the JOIN queries get built using subqueries, since the code is selecting only certain properties on our models. DeletedOn is filtered on all queries and subqueries. Also, since the application is multi-tenant, the WorkspaceId is filtered in queries and subqueries as well. Since WorkspaceId is not part of the clustered index (PK), the joins are made using only the Ids of the tables.

Running the query above was taking quite some time. Checking the Actual Query Plan, the subquery was returning millions of rows (whole table) and using the wrong index. But, running the subquery directly only a few rows were actually being returned.

As an attempt to fix, I ran the following command: `UPDATE STATISTICS dbo.Projects`

It fixed the issue, the right index got selected and now the query ran super fast. The problem is that the day after, the same issue happened again. Once again, updating the statistics fixed the issue.

Unfortunately, I don't see a manual update of the statistics to be a permanent solution.

I already ruled out index fragmentation as the root cause. I am wondering what is actually happening to cause the statistics to get so outdated that causes such a simple subquery to return the entire table instead of the actual query result.

Comment: What does `select is_auto_update_stats_on, is_auto_create_stats_on, is_auto_update_stats_async_on, is_auto_create_stats_incremental_on
from sys.databases
where name = 'YourDbName'` return

Comment: "Unfortunately, I don't see a manual update of the statistics to be a permanent solution." - you should have an automated job to refresh stats at least weekly, (sometime nightly on systems with high DML throughput)

Comment: Is the actual query parameterised? The issue may be parameter sniffing.

Comment: Probably what is happening is that the server is having to choose between two bad plans. Please show the full table and indexe definitions, and please share the query plan via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan